What is the Scope of Rabbeinu Bachya's ואין לו לבקש סבה / to NOT Look for “Natural” Ways (to Survive/Escape)?
Rabbeinu Bachya states in his intro to Parshat Miketz:
השמיני הוא שיבטח בהקב"ה בכל לבו ולא יתלה מחשבתו לסבה מן הסבות רק שירצה במה שהוא רצון הקב"ה, כלומר במה שהוא בריא או חולה עשיר או עני חפשי או אסור בבית האסורים. וכיון שרצון הקב"ה שיהיה לו אחד מן המאורעות והיסורין ההם והוא חפץ לדכאו בהם יש לו לחפוץ בזה ואין לו לבקש סבה, כי אם הוא משתדל ומבקש סבה שינצל מן המאורע ההוא שהוא בו, משים חלק אחד מלבו בבטחון אותה סבה ואיננו בוטח בהקב"ה בטחון שלם בכל לבו, ומי שהוא שלם במדת הבטחון יש עליו לבטוח בהקב"ה בכל לבו שהוא יתעלה בעל הסבות כולן יזמין אליו הסבות כפי מה שיצטרך.The eighth and final stage in his development is reached when he realizes that only G’d’s input determines his success or failure. He must learn to be happy with whatever G’d has decided should be his fate. He must give G’d credit for his health — or otherwise; he must give G’d all the credit for his wealth — or otherwise. He must appreciate that if G’d saw fit to subject him to trials and tribulations in his life on earth, that G’d had a benevolent purpose in all this, that He has his best interests at heart. G’d is equally active in protecting someone’s freedom or keeping him in jail. Seeing that G’d’s superior wisdom decrees if man is to undergo afflictions of one sort or another, it behooves man to accept such afflictions willingly. He is not to look for “natural” ways to escape such predicaments. If he does so, this demonstrates that his faith in God is not absolute, but that part of his being is still convinced that he can escape what is decreed for him.
R"B continues:
ויראה לי כי מפני זה אמר (משלי ג) בטח אל ה', ולא אמר בה', לבאר שהבטחון השלם בכל לבו הוא שיהיו כל מחשבותיו אל ה', כענין שכתוב (תהילים כ״ה:ט״ו) עיני תמיד אל ה', ואין ראוי לו לצדיק השלם במדת הבטחון לבקש סבה, והעד על זה ענין אליהו, וכמו שהזכרתי בפרשה של מעלה (מלכים א י״ז:ו׳) והעורבים מביאים לו לחם ובשר בבקר וגו', והקב"ה הזמין לו אותה סבה והוא לא בקש אותה, והנה זאת מדרגה עליונה מאד במדת הבטחון.
It appears to me that when we keep in mind these comments of the author of חובת הלבבות, we can better appreciate why Solomon wrote in Proverbs 3,5: בטח אל ה' בכל לבך, “trust towards G’d with all your heart,” instead of writing בטח בה' בכל לבך, “trust in G’d with all your heart.” He wanted to alert us that a person who truly puts his faith in G’d is someone whose thoughts are oriented only towards G’d. Another example of such a construction is found in Psalms 25,15 עיני תמיד אל ה', “my eyes are ever toward G’d.” We have already mentioned that Elijah was a prime example of someone who did not try and survive by looking for logical means to do so, but that he took refuge in a place where there was no possible chance to find food and that he relied on G’d to provide it for him in His own way. This is the highest level of trust in G’d.
והנה יוסף הצדיק הבוטח בהקב"ה לפי שבקש משר המשקים שיהיה לו סבה שיצא מבית האסורים, לכך לא הגיע למדרגה זו של בטחון ונענש בזה
By asking the Chief of the butlers to intercede on his behalf, righteous Joseph demonstrated that he had not attained the level of trust in G’d which an Elijah demonstrated in his life. As a result Joseph was punished by having to stay in jail two years longer than had been decreed originally.
*Does he mean that ideally a person should not seek medical attention when they are sick? Physical or Emotional therapy? Is it far from ideal to send a flare up into the sky when one is lost? Would Elijah have been guilty of seeking a natural means to survive had he hid in a more populous area where there is a greater chance of finding food? If someone steals from you why inform the authorities (trust in God's decree)? * Is the famous Two Boats and a Helicopter joke completely off mark (the punchline is that the departed man meets God and asks why He did not intervene. God responds that He sent all the would-be rescuers to the man's aid on the expectation he would accept the help)?

With respect to the helicopter joke, that would just be accepting help directly from G-d, similar to Elijah accepting food from the raven. The issue seems to be about proactively chasing solutions, especially when it involves beseeching a human instead of Hashem, as he explains earlier. Still an interesting question though. It sounds like a true tzaddik would indeed be expected not to send up that flare. And of course there's the famous medical book hidden by Chizkiya so the people would turn Hashem to cure their illnesses.

I can't remember the source (I'll look for it later, Bli neder) that how much hishtadlut you put in is meant to be correlated to how much bitachon (or maybe how much of a tzadik) you are. Each person should put in the effort required of his level.

See also this talk by the Lubavitcher Rebbe where it's explained that there are two modes of service, corresponding to the two forms of divine energy known as ממלא and סובב (immanent and transcendent), and that the level described by R' Bachye is primarily for the rare individual who has attained the higher level of service and connection to Hashem which entirely transcends nature, such that he can fully rely on heavenly sustenance without any physical investment.
